# Creating a real overlay in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'd like to create a frame where, in one of the overlays, a large block is printed on top of everything else, something like:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Sed aliquet imperdiet posuere.
\item Donec hendrerit orci sit amet tortor malesuada, quis maximus quam mollis.
\item Pellentesque aliquam convallis enim.
\end{itemize}

\begin{block}<2>{Title}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

But where the block (which may have some transparency) is overlaid on top of the list, with both list and block appearing where they would, without the other. I want a kind of overprint, but with overlapping overlay specifications.

Is this already covered in the manual? Any ideas?

EDIT: This is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Sed aliquet imperdiet posuere.
\item Donec hendrerit orci sit amet tortor malesuada, quis maximus quam mollis.
\item Pellentesque aliquam convallis enim.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Sample}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\paperwidth]{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Sed aliquet imperdiet posuere.
\item Donec hendrerit orci sit amet tortor malesuada, quis maximus quam mollis.
\item Pellentesque aliquam convallis enim.
\end{itemize}

\begin{block}<2>{Sample}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\paperwidth]{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and what I want is the positions of the first two frames to be maintained in the third (and the list to be always visible, although covered by the block).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I got all the parts of your question, anyway, maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Sed aliquet imperdiet posuere.
\item Donec hendrerit orci sit amet tortor malesuada, quis maximus quam mollis.
\item Pellentesque aliquam convallis enim.
\end{itemize}

\onslide<2>{
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node[opacity=.5] at(current page.center){\includegraphics[scale=.5]{figure}};
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to compile twice to get the correct positioning.

Second version:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Sed aliquet imperdiet posuere.
\item Donec hendrerit orci sit amet tortor malesuada, quis maximus quam mollis.
\item Pellentesque aliquam convallis enim.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Sample}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\paperwidth]{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Sed aliquet imperdiet posuere.
\item Donec hendrerit orci sit amet tortor malesuada, quis maximus quam mollis.
\item Pellentesque aliquam convallis enim.
\end{itemize}

\onslide<2>{
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node at(current page text area.center){
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Sample}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\paperwidth]{figure}
        \end{block}
    \end{minipage}
    };
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the gif the positions are exactly the same as the single frames.

Comment: Close, but: (1) I want the whole `block` environment to be overlaid like that (don't worry about the transparency, I have that fixed), it seems this solution does not work with that; and (2) I'd prefer not to use absolute positioning, especially when title- and sidebars may change the actual text area.

Comment: What do you mean with: "the whole block"? If you want a beamer block to be in the overlay, you may just add `\begin{block}...\end{block}` inside the node. For (2), you want relative positioning with respect to what?

Comment: I tried that, but I got a missing \endgroup error, so either. And for the positioning, I want its "natural" place, where it would appear on its own. I'll update the question with a more complete sample.

Comment: You need to enclose the block into a minipage to put it into a TikZ node.

Comment: OK, with the minipage it works, thanks. In this second version the block appears significantly lower than in the single frame. Not a big deal, and I could always tweak it manually, but this keeps me wishing for another solution. And in my case the text moves up a similar amount; this happens even with an empty `\tikz[overlay,remember picture];`, but not with an empty `\onslide<2>{}`